# iOS iCloud: Delete all file issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdk, icloud

We have one feature of iCloud backup. I am using [iCloudDocumentSync](https://github.com/iRareMedia/iCloudDocumentSync) library for it. I am facing issue delete all files from iCloud.
When i try to delete all file after upload file, it is working perfectly but when i try to delete all files after downloading file , delete is not working

Here is my download files code

```
[[iCloud sharedCloud] retrieveCloudDocumentWithName:filename completion:^(UIDocument *cloudDocument, NSData *documentData, NSError *error) {
        if (!error)
        {
            NSData *fileData = documentData;
            NSError *err = nil;
            NSDictionary *JSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:fileData options:0 error:&err];
            [cloudDocument closeWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success){
                if (success) {
                }
            }];
        }
}];
```

And delete all files from iCloud code

```
[[[iCloud sharedCloud]listCloudFiles] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *listname, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
         {
             if ([listname isKindOfClass:[NSURL class]])
             {
                 listname= [listname lastPathComponent];
             }
             [[iCloud sharedCloud] deleteDocumentWithName:listname completion:^(NSError *error)
              {
                  if (error) {
                  } else {
                      [[iCloud sharedCloud] updateFiles];
                      int value =   (int)[[iCloud sharedCloud]listCloudFiles].count;
                      if (!error && value == 0)
                      {
                      }
                      else if(error && value == 1){
                      }
                  }
              }];
}]
```